# App Engine JSP without code inside

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

Is it possible to use JSP sort of as a template without having code inside?

Values should be inserted into a hash map, and the JSP can read the values from there.

Is it possible to code like this in a GAE application, or do you need external tools/frameworks to accomplish this?

In other words, is it possible to pass values from the servlet handler to the JSP template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next to JSP there's also the Servlet API.

If the map is request or session specific, then create a class which extends [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) and implement `doGet()` method like follows:

```
Map<K, V> map = createItSomehow();
request.setAttribute("map", map);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Register the `Servlet` in `web.xml` on a certain `url-pattern` and invoke an URL matching this pattern.

This way the `map` is available as `${map}` in JSP. Here's an example which iterates over the `map` using [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) `c:forEach` tag:

```
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    Key: ${entry.key}, Value: ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

If the map is an application wide constant, then rather implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and do the following in `contextInitialized()` method:

```
Map<K, V> map = createItSomehow();
event.getServletContext().setAttribute("map", map);
```

Register the `ServletContextListener` in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and it will be executed on webapp's startup. The `map` is then available in JSP by `${map}` as well.

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)
- [Hidden features of JSP/Servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/01/hidden-features-of-jspservlet.html)
- [Coreservlets.com JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)